# Extracting the contents of the Xcode XIP file on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, xcode, archive

I am having some trouble extracting the Xcode 8 XIP I downloaded from Apple. After trying to extract it, I get the following error:

> The operation couldn't be completed. cpio read error: Undefined error: 0

I looked into the problem and found it is because Xcode 8 will not run on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, which I am running.

I just need the iOS 10.0.1 DeveloperDiskImage from the file, and I am not planning on installing it, so why can't I just extract the archive, take the file, then delete the archive? Does anyone know any workarounds for this? Can anyone give me a copy of the DeveloperDiskImage from their Xcode 8 installation?

Comment: Xcode 8 requires a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12 or OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 or later. The Xcode_8.xip file will extract just fine under a supported OS version.

Comment: I don't need to install it, I just need a file from the archive and I am running an unsupported version.